# Github Actions CI: Exporting cmake, ninja to GITHUB_PATH via a python script

Tags: cmake, path, continuous-integration, github-actions, ninja

I am trying to setup a build workflow for my c++ project using a python script and github action, I have setup my workflow to run a build script on windows-latest, ubuntu-latest and macos-latest. I am stuck at the step in which I download cmake and ninja. The script succeeds only on windows but fails on ubuntu and macos bc it can't recognize `ninja` even though I downloaded the binary and exported the path to `GITHUB_PATH` but somehow it cmake works fine even though I followed the same exact steps that I used to install ninja.

Here is the work flow script:

```yaml
name: Build Matrix

####
# triggers for workflow
####
on: [push, pull_request, workflow_dispatch]

###
# preset enviroment variables
###
env:
  CMAKE_VERSION: 3.24.3
  NINJA_VERSION: 1.11.1
  BUILD_TYPE: Release
  CCACHE_VERSION: 4.7.3

###
# Jobs: filter_path, build
###

###
jobs:
  ###
  # paths-filter: 
    ## Tracks any changes in the specified directories and outputs `exec_build` 
    ## if `exec_build` is true, then build job is launched.
  ###
  paths-filter:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      exec_build: ${{ steps.filter.outputs.workflows }}
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: dorny/paths-filter@v2
      id: filter
      with:
        filters: |
          workflows:
            - '.github/workflows/build_project.yaml'
            - 'CMakeLists.txt'
            - 'Doxyfile'
            - '.gitignore'
            - 'include/**'
            - 'src/**'
            - 'test/**'
            - 'scripts/**'
            - 'examples/**'
            - 'utils/**'
            - 'libs/'

  build:
    name: ${{ matrix.config.name }}
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.config.os }}
    needs: paths-filter
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        config:
        - {
            name: "Windows Latest MSVC", artifact: "Windows-MSVC.7z",
            os: windows-latest,
            cc: "cl", cxx: "cl",
            environment_script: "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Enterprise/VC/Auxiliary/Build/vcvars64.bat"
          }
        - {
            name: "Ubuntu Latest GCC", artifact: "Linux.7z",
            os: ubuntu-latest,
            cc: "gcc", cxx: "g++"
          }
        - {
            name: "macOS Latest Clang", artifact: "macOS.7z",
            os: macos-latest,
            cc: "clang", cxx: "clang++"
          }
    if: needs.paths-filter.outputs.exec_build == 'true'
    steps:
    # checkout the repo into the workspace
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    # setup python for scripting
    - name: Set up Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v4
      with:
          python-version: '3.10'
          cache: 'pip'

    - name: Install pip packages
      id: install-packages
      run: |
        pip install -r scripts/requirements.txt
    
    # download ninja and cmake
    - name: Download Ninja and CMake
      shell: bash
      run:  |
        python scripts/download-ninja-cmake.py
        # For debugging
        cat $GITHUB_PATH
        cmake --version
        ninja --version
```

Here is the python script `scripts/download-ninja-cmake.py`:

```py
import subprocess
from os import environ, path

from detect_os import detect_os
from setup_cmake import get_url as get_cmake_url
from setup_ninja import get_url as get_ninja_url
from extract_arcv import extract_here
from github_env import GITHUB_WORKSPACE, GITHUB_PATH, RUNNER_OS
from download import download
from command_runner import command

CMAKE_VERSION = environ.get('CMAKE_VERSION')
NINJA_VERSION = environ.get('NINJA_VERSION')


print(f"Detected OS: {RUNNER_OS})")
# See Github enviroment variables
print("Enviroment: ")
subprocess.run(["env"])

"""Notes
* GITHUB_WORKSPACE, GITHUB_PATH, RUNNER_OS
enviroment variables that I creating using GITHUB_VARIABLE = os.environ['GITHUB_VARIABLE']
* get_cmake_url(version : str) -> str and get_ninja_url(version : str) -> str:
puts together the url used to download cmake and ninja respectively

* download(url : str) -> str 
downloads cmake and ninja then it outputs the absolute path of the downloaded archive.

* extract_here(compressed_file : str) -> str:
behaves similar the GUI `extract here` in ubuntu, and it outputs the absolute path to the extracted content

* command(cmd:str):
is just an abstraction for the function: subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True)
"""

# 
# extract_here
print(f"Downloading CMake v{CMAKE_VERSION}")
url = get_cmake_url(CMAKE_VERSION)
print(f"CMake Download URL: {url}")
cmake_out_arcv = download(url)
print(f"Downloaded: {cmake_out_arcv}")

print(f"Extracting {cmake_out_arcv}: ")
cmake_dir = extract_here(cmake_out_arcv)
print(f"Extracted: {cmake_dir}")

if RUNNER_OS == "Windows":
    cmake_dir = f"cmake-{CMAKE_VERSION}-windows-x86_64/ cmake-{CMAKE_VERSION}-windows-x86_64/bin"
elif RUNNER_OS == "Linux":
    cmake_dir = f"cmake-{CMAKE_VERSION}-linux-x86_64/cmake-{CMAKE_VERSION}-linux-x86_64/bin"
elif RUNNER_OS == "macOS":
    cmake_dir = f"cmake-{CMAKE_VERSION}-macos-universal/cmake-{CMAKE_VERSION}-macos-universal/CMake.app/Contents/bin"
    
cmake_dir = path.join(GITHUB_WORKSPACE, cmake_dir)

# -------------------

print(f"Downloading Ninja v{NINJA_VERSION}")
ninja_url = get_ninja_url(NINJA_VERSION)
print(f"Ninja Download URL: {ninja_url}")
ninja_out_arcv = download(ninja_url)
print(f"Downloaded: {ninja_out_arcv}")

print(f"Extracting {ninja_out_arcv}: ")
ninja_dir = extract_here(ninja_out_arcv)
print(f"Extracted: {ninja_dir}")

if RUNNER_OS != "windows":
    # Exports both ninja_dir and cmake_dir
    command(f'echo "{ninja_dir}:{cmake_dir}" >> $GITHUB_PATH ')
    command(f"chmod +x {ninja_dir}/ninja")
    command(f"chmod +x {cmake_dir}/cmake")
```

Here is the output log on ubuntu-latest:

```
Run python scripts/download-ninja-cmake.py:

Detected OS: Linux
Downloading CMake v3.24.3
CMake Download URL: https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.24.3/cmake-3.24.3-linux-x86_64.tar.gz

.. download progress logs ..

Downloaded: /home/runner/work/cxx_project_template/cxx_project_template/cmake-3.24.3-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
Extracting /home/runner/work/cxx_project_template/cxx_project_template/cmake-3.24.3-linux-x86_64.tar.gz: 
Extracted: /home/runner/work/cxx_project_template/cxx_project_template/cmake-3.24.3-linux-x86_64

Downloading Ninja v1.11.1

.. download progress logs ..

Downloaded: /home/runner/work/cxx_project_template/cxx_project_template/ninja-linux.zip
Extracting /home/runner/work/cxx_project_template/cxx_project_template/ninja-linux.zip: 
Extracted: /home/runner/work/cxx_project_template/cxx_project_template/ninja-linux


cmake version 3.25.1

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
/home/runner/work/_temp/6470193b-ec2e-4d49-bddf-10d580c046a4.sh: line 4: ninja: command not found
Error: Process completed with exit code 127.
```

-- update --

Here is how `GITHUB_PATH` looks like after executing the script:

```
/home/runner/work/cxx_project_template/cxx_project_template/ninja-linux:/home/runner/work/cxx_project_template/cxx_project_template/cmake-3.24.3-linux-x86_64/cmake-3.24.3-linux-x86_64/bin
```

Somehow it works on windows, even though I haven't exported the path to cmake neither ninja, but it fails to work on unix based os's.

Comment: The default installed `cmake` won't work for your use case? You could use https://github.com/lukka/get-cmake to install `cmake` and `ninja` as well. Why are you doing it yourself? It's just more code to write, test, and maintain.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [preinstalled software](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#preinstalled-software) for your target runners.